# Is there a way to get the "Paste from Other Apps" setting value?

Tags: ios

Is there a way to programmatically get the value of this setting's value?

There are three options: 1. Ask, 2. Allow, 3. Deny.
By default it is set to Ask.

[image: Settings option]

Or do you know if it is possible to check the permission and allow it in the app?

I didn't find anything like that on `UIPasteboard` or `UIPasteConfiguration` documentation.

Answer (score -1):

I did not find any API for this. I am also searching it. I don't think there is any.
Now, I am thinking that maybe I can start a timer in another thread for 0.5 seconds and if we have not yet received the data from UIPasteboard, then either the dialog has been shown to user, or user has denied the permission and it wont paste. At this point maybe, we need to give some alert to the user and redirect them to Setting maybe.